# How can I find files and folders whose names start with a dot?

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to write a script to recursively descend into a directory structure to find `*.sm` and `*.ssc` files. However, my script skips over folders whose names start with a dot, for example `.Folder Name`. This is on Windows - the folder is not hidden.

An example of a correct result it finds:

```
/mydir/Directory Name/File Name.sm
```

An example of a file it does not find:

```
/mydir/.Directory Name/.File Name.sm
```

```
function findFiles($directory) {
    function glob_recursive($directory, &$directories = array()) {
        foreach(glob($directory, GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT) as $folder) {
            $directories[] = $folder;
            glob_recursive("{$folder}/*", $directories);
        }
    }
    glob_recursive($directory, $directories);
    $files = array ();
    foreach($directories as $directory) {
    $directory = str_replace(['[',']',"\f[","\f]"], ["\f[","\f]",'[[]','[]]'], $directory);
    foreach(glob("{$directory}/*.{sm,ssc}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: could you clarify please - the title says `files and folders whose names start with a dot` yet the question suggests that you also wish to find files with either `sm` or `ssc` file extensions. Is it both that you wish to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [comment](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/623911f993f39ebbe75abe2771fc89faf6b15b9b/win32/glob.c#L661) in the source code:

> Initial DOT must be matched literally.

So though a folder starts with dot isn't hidden in windows, php still regards it as a special name.

```
glob('.*');
```

This returns file or folder start with dot.

So a full list can be

```
array_merge(glob('.*'), glob('*'));
```